# Numbering the latest row inserted

Tags: excel, sequence, rows

How do I automatically number the latest row that was inserted into the sheet?
For example, I have 100 numbered rows, now when I insert a new row in the 56th row, it should be numbered at 101. Could you please help me out with this?

Comment: This will require vba. A formula will not do it and there is no built in method to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume that the number is stored in column **A**.  Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Rows.Count = 1 And .Columns.Count = Columns.Count Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Target(1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A")) + 1
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            Else
                Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

When an entire row is inserted, the resulting `Target` will have one row and 16384 columns.

Note that you can fool the macro by `Selecting` an entire row and putting a value in all the cells.  So don't do that.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**